# Get aggregate quantity from JOINED tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following two tables in my database

inventory_transactions table

```
    
  id |        date_created        | company_id | product_id | quantity | amount | is_verified | buy_or_sell_to | transaction_type | parent_tx | invoice_id | order_id | transaction_comment
----+----------------------------+------------+------------+----------+--------+-------------+----------------+------------------+-----------+------------+----------+---------------------
  1 | 2022-04-25 10:42:00.627495 |         20 |        100 |       23 |   7659 | t           |                | BUY              |           |          1 |          |
  2 | 2022-04-25 10:48:48.02342  |         21 |          2 |       10 |    100 | t           |                | BUY              |           |          2 |          |
  3 | 2022-04-25 11:00:11.624176 |         21 |          7 |       10 |    100 | t           |                | BUY              |           |          3 |          |
  4 | 2022-04-25 11:08:14.607117 |         23 |          1 |       11 |   1210 | t           |                | BUY              |           |          4 |          |
  5 | 2022-04-25 11:13:24.084845 |         23 |         28 |       16 |   2560 | t           |                | BUY              |           |          5 |          |
  6 | 2022-04-25 11:26:56.338881 |         23 |         28 |       15 |   3525 | t           |              5 | BUY              |           |          6 |        1 |
  7 | 2022-04-25 11:26:56.340112 |          5 |         28 |       15 |   3525 | t           |             23 | SELL             |         6 |          6 |        1 |
  8 | 2022-04-25 11:30:08.529288 |         23 |         30 |       65 |  15925 | t           |              5 | BUY              |           |          7 |        2 |
  9 | 2022-04-25 11:30:08.531005 |          5 |         30 |       65 |  15925 | t           |             23 | SELL             |         8 |          7 |        2 |
 14 | 2022-04-25 12:28:51.658902 |         23 |         28 |      235 |  55225 | t           |              5 | BUY              |           |         11 |        5 |
 15 | 2022-04-25 12:28:51.660478 |          5 |         28 |      235 |  55225 | t           |             23 | SELL             |        14 |         11 |        5 |
 20 | 2022-04-25 13:01:31.091524 |         20 |          4 |        4 |    176 | t           |                | BUY              |           |         15 |          |
 10 | 2022-04-25 11:50:48.4519   |         21 |         38 |        1 |     10 | t           |                | BUY              |           |          8 |          |
 11 | 2022-04-25 11:50:48.454118 |         21 |         36 |        1 |     10 | t           |                | BUY              |           |          8 |          |
 12 | 2022-04-25 11:52:19.827671 |         21 |         29 |        1 |     10 | t           |                | BUY              |           |          9 |          |
 13 | 2022-04-25 11:53:16.699881 |         21 |         74 |        1 |     10 | t           |                | BUY              |           |         10 |          |
 16 | 2022-04-25 12:37:39.739125 |         20 |          1 |      228 |  58824 | t           |                | BUY              |           |         12 |          |
 17 | 2022-04-25 12:37:39.741106 |         20 |          3 |      228 |  58824 | t           |                | BUY              |           |         12 |          |
 18 | 2022-04-25 12:49:09.922686 |         21 |         41 |       10 |   1000 | t           |                | BUY              |           |         13 |          |
 19 | 2022-04-25 12:55:11.986451 |         20 |          5 |       22 |    484 | t           |                | BUY              |           |         14 |          |
```

**NOTE** each transaction in the `inventory_transactions` table is recorded twice with the `company_id` and `buy_or_sell_to` swapped for the 2nd row and `transaction_type` BUY or SELL reserved. (similar to how a journal is menatained in accounting).

```
 db# select * from inventory_transactions where buy_or_sell_to is not Null order by date_created limit 50;
 id |        date_created        | company_id | product_id | quantity | amount | is_verified | buy_or_sell_to | transaction_type | parent_tx | invoice_id | order_id | transaction_comment
----+----------------------------+------------+------------+----------+--------+-------------+----------------+------------------+-----------+------------+----------+---------------------
  6 | 2022-04-25 11:26:56.338881 |         23 |         28 |       15 |   3525 | t           |              5 | BUY              |           |          6 |        1 |
  7 | 2022-04-25 11:26:56.340112 |          5 |         28 |       15 |   3525 | t           |             23 | SELL             |         6 |          6 |        1 |
  8 | 2022-04-25 11:30:08.529288 |         23 |         30 |       65 |  15925 | t           |              5 | BUY              |           |          7 |        2 |
  9 | 2022-04-25 11:30:08.531005 |          5 |         30 |       65 |  15925 | t           |             23 | SELL             |         8 |          7 |        2 |
```

companies table (consider this as the users table, in my project all users are companies)

```
 id | company_type |      gstin      |    name     |  phone_no  | address | pincode | is_hymbee_verified | is_active | district_id | pancard_no
----+--------------+-----------------+-------------+------------+---------+---------+--------------------+-----------+-------------+------------
 26 | RETAILER     | XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX | ACD LLC     | 12345%7898 | AQWSAQW | 319401  |                    |           |          11 | AQWSDERFVV  
 27 | DISTRIBUTOR  | XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX | CDF LLC     | 123XX7898  | AGWSAQW | 319201  |                    |           |          13 | AQWSDERFVV  
 28 | RETAILER     | XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX | !@# LLC     | 1234!67XX9 | AQCCAQW | 319101  |                    |           |          16 | AQWSDERFVV  
 29 | COMPANY      | XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX | ZAZ LLC     | 123456S898 | AQWQQQW | 319001  |                    |           |          19 | AQWSDERFVV
```

### Problem statement

The query I am trying to write will fetch quantity sold only to users who are `RETAILER`s and `DISTRIBUTORS` by users who are either a `RETAILER` or a `DISTRIBUTOR`.

for example, if a user is a `RETAILER`, we need to calculate how much quantity this `RETAILER` has sold to other users who are either `RETAILER` or `DISTRIBUTOR`s.

In other words, for all rows in the `companies` table check if the `company` is of `company_type`, `RETAILER` or `DISTRIBUTOR` and from the `inventory_transactions` table, check how much `quantity` a partiuclar `RETAILER` OR `DISTRIBUTOR` has sold to other `RETAILER`s and `DISTRIBUTOR`s

I have very basic knowledge of SQL and have only gotten so far:

```
select Seller.id as Seller_ROW, Buyer.id as Buyer_row, Seller.company_id, Buyer.buy_or_sell_to, Seller.company_type as Seller_Type, Buyer.company_type as Buyer_Type, Seller.quantity, Buyer.quantity
FROM 
(select t.id, t.company_id, t.quantity, c.company_type
from inventory_transactions as t
join companies as c on c.id = t.company_id
where c.company_type = 'RETAILER' or company_type = 'DISTRIBUTOR'
) as Seller
JOIN
(select t.id, t.buy_or_sell_to, t.quantity, c.company_type
from inventory_transactions as t
join companies as c on c.id = t.buy_or_sell_to
where c.company_type = 'RETAILER' or company_type = 'DISTRIBUTOR') as Buyer on Seller.id = Buyer.id
```

output

```
 seller_row | buyer_row | company_id | buy_or_sell_to | seller_type | buyer_type  | quantity | quantity
------------+-----------+------------+----------------+-------------+-------------+----------+----------
         25 |        25 |         22 |             25 | RETAILER    | DISTRIBUTOR |        1 |        1
         26 |        26 |         25 |             22 | DISTRIBUTOR | RETAILER    |        1 |        1
         31 |        31 |         37 |             43 | DISTRIBUTOR | RETAILER    |       10 |       10
         32 |        32 |         43 |             37 | RETAILER    | DISTRIBUTOR |       10 |       10
         33 |        33 |         21 |             43 | DISTRIBUTOR | RETAILER    |        1 |        1
         34 |        34 |         43 |             21 | RETAILER    | DISTRIBUTOR |        1 |        1
         35 |        35 |         21 |             49 | DISTRIBUTOR | RETAILER    |        1 |        1
         36 |        36 |         49 |             21 | RETAILER    | DISTRIBUTOR |        1 |        1
         37 |        37 |         21 |             51 | DISTRIBUTOR | RETAILER    |        1 |        1
         38 |        38 |         51 |             21 | RETAILER    | DISTRIBUTOR |        1 |        1
```

There are duplicate rows in the resulting table and so i am unable to do a `SUM()`.

Expected result

```
SELLER.company_id   |   SELLER.company_name     |   SELLER.company_type     |   QUANTITY    | BUYER.company_type
    26              |   XYZ Retail Co.          |            RETAILER       |   14          |   RETAILER
    26              |   XYZ Retail Co.          |            RETAILER       |   1           |   DISTRIBUTOR
    27              |   ACD Distributions       |            DISTRIBUTOR    |   0           |   RETAILER
    27              |   ACD Distributions       |            DISTRIBUTOR    |   10          |   DISTRIBUTOR
```

Comment: What's your expect result from your sample data?

Comment: The sample data you provided for both your input tables is insufficient to answer this question properly.

Comment: @D-Shih i have added the expected result to the question

Comment: @lemon i have added more data to `inventory_transactions` table

Comment: it's a good improvement @s13rw81, though the output you get does not match the application of your query to the current provided inputs, can you adjust your post accordingly?

Comment: @lemon I am unable to improve on this any further, that's about all the SQL that I know and could Google since I was given to write this query. I am really sorry. I figure, I have to check all the rows in `inventory_transactions` table and check `company_id` which is the id of the `Seller` company and check if it is either a `Retailer` or a `Distributor` from the companies table, then aggregate the `Quantity` for only those rows where the companies in the `sell_to_or_buy_to` column which has `company_id`s of Buyers are Retailers or Distributors.

Comment: In your COMPANIES table, every row has the same ID value. I assume this is a typo - if it is please could you correct it so that this data lines up with your expected result?

Comment: @NickW i have made changes to the table. i had copied one row over and over and had only edited the `company_type` to show the different company types there could be.

Comment: It’s difficult to help you when the information you provide is not consistent - running the SQL you’ve provided against the sample data will not produce the result you’ve given. Please amend your question so that the sample data, SQL, result from the SQL and the result you want to achieve are all consistent

Comment: @NickW could you kindly elaborate so that i can improve the question. I have posted the `companies` and the `inventory_transactions` table using basic `select * from <table_name>` and posted the half cooked SQL that i could come up with and the result it produces out of the database. The expected result is all the information i am looking to fetch. please could you give some more information as to what i could add to improve this answer. i think @lemon is also facing the same issue but I am not sure what i could do.

Comment: Is it correct that every sale will be represented as two rows in `inventory_transactions`: one with a `transaction_type` of `BUY`, and another with `transaction_type` of `SELL` and the `company_id` and `buy_or_sell_to` values swapped?

Comment: It sure looks to me like `id` 6 and 7 are describing the same sale (company 5 selling 15 units to company 23 for 3525 money) from both the buyer and seller perspectives. In fact, the `parent_tx` of the `SELL` row references the `id` of the `BUY` row.

Comment: @FredSobotka you are correct. Upon further investigation i have noticed that **every transaction is noted twice** in the `inventory_transactions` table with the values in `company_id` switched with `buy_to_or_sell_to` and `transaction_type` reversed (BUY becomes SELL and SELL becomes BUY`

Comment: In your SQL, the seller id is coming from the transaction id. In your sample data the transaction id has values 1 to 19. The result you say your SQL is giving has seller ids of 28 to 35 - therefore at least one of your sample data, SQL or result must be incompatible with the other 2

Comment: @nickW the `inventory_transactions` table records BUY or SELL transactions with `company_id` showing the SELLER of the item and `buy_or_sell_to` showing the BUYER of the item. in the result of the SQL statement, `seller_row | buyer_row` are only the row numbers from the `inventory_transactions` table. in the `companies` table, `id` is the primary key in the `companies` table and these companies buy or sell items which are recorded in the `inventory_transactions` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes that every sale is represented as two rows in `inventory_transactions`, which makes it possible to avoid duplicates by working with only one `transaction_type`, so we'll filter on `SELL` transactions.

```
SELECT t.company_id AS seller_company_id
, s.company_name AS seller_company_name
, s.company_type AS seller_company_type
, SUM(t.quantity) AS quantity
, b.company_type AS buyer_company_type
FROM inventory_transactions AS t
INNER JOIN companies AS s
ON s.id = t.company_id
INNER JOIN companies AS b
ON b.id = buy_or_sell_to
WHERE t.transaction_type = 'SELL'
AND s.company_type IN ('RETAILER','DISTRIBUTOR')
AND b.company_type IN ('RETAILER','DISTRIBUTOR')
GROUP BY t.company_id, s.company_name, s.company_type, b.company_type
ORDER BY seller_company_id, seller_company_name, seller_company_type, buyer_company_type
;
```

Comment: The query in this answer uses inner joins for simplicity, and the summary it produces will not show any rows with a quantity of zero. If every seller and buyer category must appear in the final result, even if zero units were sold, the query will need some minor adjustments.

Comment: i ran your query and have posted the results here https://pastebin.com/rTETLprY

Comment: the answer may not be what i needed as every Seller who is a RETAILER or a DISTRIBUTOR needs to have two rows for itself, one which SUMs the quantity it sold to RETAILERS another that SUMs the quantity it sold to DISTRIBUTORS

Comment: The `GROUP BY` clause includes the buyer's company type, which means each seller will have two totals if it sold units to retailers and distributors. If the seller only sold units to one of those buyer company types, then that seller will only have one summary row in the result set. If the seller sold no units to retailers or distributors, then that seller will not appear in the result set.

Comment: thank you. I have marked your answer as correct.